# Which data type should be used for prices and amounts in Firestore?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Could you tell me which data type should be using in my data class for the price of a product that needs to be stored in `Firestore`? What is your recommendation?

I a using `Kotlin`

Answer (score 1):

The choice of field type in Firestore is entirely dependent on your requirements for sorting and filtering on that field.  If you don't have any requirements, then do whatever you find most convenient.  If you do have requirements, you will need to list those out and choose the type that best suits them.  Numbers always sort numerically and strings always sort lexicographically.  If you intent to sort by these prices, a number is the only thing that makes sense (unless you are willing to pad number strings with zeroes).

Beyond that, it's impossible to say what's best for prices.  It's a complicated topic.  Do you need to support multiple currencies?  Do those currencies support fractional units (e.g. cents to the dollar)?  Do you need to use these values for mathematical operations?  Which operations?  Is it OK if an operation (e.g. division) loses precision for a fractional unit (which could result in a loss of money value), if you need to support them?  There are a lot of considerations.  I suggest listing out your requirements, then figuring out something that suits your requirements.